# Shvus dshvus dshvus

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, derabanan

I've heard that *shvus dshvus dshvus* (like asking a non-Jew to do a *melacha drabbanun* with a *shinui* is permissible. Is that only *bidieved* or *lichatchilah* as well? Also is it a *machlokes*? Please bring sources.

Comment: related halacha 12 here http://www.chabad.org/3775907/ and this https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.307.5

Comment: Everything's a machlokes. :)

Answer (score 1):

R Daniel Braude ([Learn Shabbos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1988022304), p.p. 534-35) explains this is indeed possible but the details are a *machloket*. He permits telling a non-Jew to do a *melachah* with a *shinui* in cases where the result will be inferior. Specifically

> When a Torah *melachah* is performed with a *shinui* it is no longer
> classified as a Torah prohibition, as it has changed from the typical
> *melachah* itself. However it is still Rabinically prohibited. Is the *halacha* in a case of a *melachah* done with a *shinui* more stringent than the Rabbinic prohibitions mentioned above, because the
> *melachah* itself is still occurring?
>
> There is much debate about this. Although the *Mishnah Berurah* is
> lenient in certain cases, one must consult a Rav before applying this
> leniency to a *melachah* that is done with a *shinui*.
>
> As a guideline, the following thought process is considered credible,
> and may be applied: R Yosef Shalom Elyashiv (Orchos Shabbos 23, fn 179) and R Shlomo Zalman
> Auerbach (Shmirat Shabbat Kehilchata 30, fn 49) distinguished between a *shinui* that produces an inferior
> result to what would result with a normal *melachah*, and a *shinui*
> that ultimately causes the same result. In both cases it is a Rabbinic
> prohibition, but where the result is inferior, it is less of a
> *melachah*, and using this leniency is permitted. However, where the result is identical, this leniency may not be used.
>
> As an example
>
> - if one taps a light switch with his elbow, it is abnormal, and qualifies as a *shinui*. However, the light would not have been
>   different if one had switched it on normally. The quality of the act
>   is the same, and so, one may not ask a non-Jew to switch a light
>   abnormally for a great personal need
> - on the other, if one writes with his weaker hand, the quality of the writing will certainly be inferior to that of his natural
>   handwriting. Therefore, one may ask a non-Jew to write with his left
>   hand in a case of great need
>
> Note that in cases in which the non-Jew was told to do the act with a
> *shinui* and he decided to do it normally, one may still benefit from that *melachah*, unless the expectation of the non-Jew doing it in
> such an unusual way was unreasonable. In other words, this leniency
> (telling a non-Jew to do a *melachah* with a *shinui* in cases where
> the result will be inferior) does not apply if the non-Jew will almost
> certainly stil do it in the normal way.

Comment: Can anyone provided sources for the rulings of Rabbis Elyashiv and Auerbach cited in this answer?

Comment: Done in the text of the answer. These are the sources provided by the author

Comment: Are these cases of a shinui on a rabbinic command? It looks like this is just shvus dshvus, not shvus dshvus dshvus

Comment: Thank you, @mbloch!